# How to extract the "href" attribute of <a> and paste it in a Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to extract an HTML anchor's ( < a href="" >Link here< /a > ) "href" attribute from the following page:

`https://tvm.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?team=2368692&championship=K%C3%B6ln-Leverkusen+Winter+2019%2F2020&group=18`

and put it in my google sheet.

I tried several xpath expressions for this page but it is everytime "N/A".

Still the simple xpath doesn't work, e.g.

```
importxml("https://tvm.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?team=2368692&championship=K%C3%B6ln-Leverkusen+Winter+2019%2F2020&group=18";"//tr")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I would like to extract a "a href" from the following page to use it in google sheets`, I cannot understand about the result you expect. So can you provide the result you expect?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english ,-) I would like to use a Website Link within google sheets. I found importxml to fetch content from a website with xpath expressions.

Comment: But for the named webpage it is impossible to fetch anything. I have no idea if the website is broken or if I misunderstood xpath ...

Comment: I think that `IMPORTXML` cannot be retrieved values from the URL. Because `=IMPORTXML(URL,"//head")` returns `#N/A`. In this case, I would like to propose to retrieve the values using Google Apps Script. When Google Apps Script is used, the HTML data is retrieved. But from your replying, I cannot understand about the result you want. So I'm not sure whether the retrieved HTML data is the data you want. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I would like to put in my google sheets a hyperlink, which is based on, e.g.

<a href="/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?federation=TVM&amp;region=DE.WE.TVM.20&amp;team=2368737">TC Ford Köln II</a>

which is embedded in the mentioned website. But I didn't find a good solution to extract this link with google script for google sheets.

Comment: The final result should be, that the script automatically generate google sheets depending on the used website, because besides the one named above, there are many more for different teams. My request here is only one part of the project idea. For the rest I have already solutions. Only extracting the links is a problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script is used, the hyperlink of `/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?federation=TVM&amp;region=DE.WE.TVM.20&amp;team=2368737` can be retrieved by parsing the retrieved HTML data. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) But unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your result values you expect. By this, I cannot propose the sample script. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Tanaike thank you for wanting to help me. 

I would like to extract that link by searching for "TC Ford Köln II" within the webpage and the result should be stored in a google sheets cell and optional as a hyperlink to the full webpage by expanding before the result with: 

https ://tvm.liga.nu/ 

So the complete hyperlink would be:

https ://tvm.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?federation=TVM&amp;region=DE.WE.TVM.20&amp;team=2368737

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script of Google Apps Script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I noticed that you had posted an answer. I deeply apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. I could know that my answer didn't resolve your issue. So I have to delete my answer Because I don't want to confuse other users. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Tanaike, many thanks for your efforts and your solution was the right one. It was impossible to place my answer in a comment to you, thats the reason why I have choosen the answer button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tanaike for all of your efforts.

I changed the script a little bit, because the result is based on pure html and needs to be changed so that the link could be clicked.

```
function getWebsite(url, searchText, baseURL)
{
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = html.getContentText();

  var re = new RegExp('(?<=<a href=")(.*)(?=">.*' + searchText +')',"g");

  var link = text.match(re)[0];

  if (link !== null) 
  {
    var link = text.match(re);
    link = link.replace(/&amp;/g,"&");
    link = link.replace(/&quot;/g,"\"");

    return baseURL + link;
  }
  else { return "not found"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends which information you're looking for, but for example...

A1: https://tvm.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/teamPortrait?team=2368692&championship=K%C3%B6ln-Leverkusen+Winter+2019%2F2020&group=18

A2: //table[2]/tbody/tr/td[6]/a/@href

A3: =IMPORTXML(A1,A2,1)

To find A2 - in Chrome - right-click a link of interest and "Inspect." Right-click on the href of interest to you, and "Copy full XPath."

Delete the part before the table reference, but leave TWO "/"s before the table reference. Then, delete the reference to the specific row following "tr", i.e., the "[x]". This way you'll select the entire column - in this case "[6]"

Fiddle as necessary.